# Firestore Database 'Post': Send to all geographic locations

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I'm not a coder but am getting to know Firestore Database.
As you can see, we have posts set up to automatically geotag based on the users present location. Only other users in a 5km sphere from the posting user will receive the post in their timeline.

My question is, through Firestore Database, is it possible to make a post non-geo specific? I would like to alter an existing post, or make a new post that all users of the app will receive, irrespective of their location.

Thanks in advance for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get database results that don't consider the geographic location, you can use the regular [Firestore query API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to do so.

Only when your query (or add-on library) includes a [filter on the geohash field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries) will the query be specific to the geo-location.